# Is this integral solvable?

Tags: integral-equations

I am trying to solve the below mentioned integral. Is it possible to solve this with mathematica. If not, can I get an approximation for this by introducting the variable not to take certain values ?

[image]

```
Integrate[
 4 x/π^2 ArcCos[(y^2 + 3)/(4 y)] ArcCos[(x^2 + y^2 - 
      1)/(2 x y)], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: Some spaces would do a lot to clarify your expression. Even better would be *Mathematica* code - have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I  have edited the post with a newer image. I do not have the software installed yet but I am looking to find out whether this solvable or not with mathmetica. I want to have value/solution to put in an expression

Comment: Better than an image would be TeX code. That would at least eliminate some work for us.

Comment: I am sorry for not providing the code since I am in the process of installing and getting to use mathemtica only solve this integral problem. If I can have an information about the solvability, it would be great. I tried the online integral calculator but it says it does not have a solution.

Comment: and I am new to Latex as well :)

Comment: (at) Waqas: The Integrand seems to be f = 4 (x y)/\[Pi]^2 ArcCos[(y^2 + 3)/(4 y)] ArcCos[(x^2 + y^2 - 1)/(
   2 x y)], but the integration region is not clearly defined. The indefinite integral over x can be done, the one over y is returned unevaluated. I guess that you have to resort to numerical integration to find the value of the integral.

Comment: You can try the free Wolfram cloud, it has Mathematica there for free http://www.wolfram.com/programming-cloud/pricing/  click on the free option. Also can try Wolfram alpha, it is supposed to be able to do integration as well.

Comment: I would require a definite integral for both x and y. By unevaluated you mean that the value does not exist or the problem is unsolvable. And secondly, would numerical integration give me a definite value for this integral ?

Comment: integrate 4 (x y)/[Pi]^2 ArcCos[(y^2 + 3)/(4 y)] ArcCos[(x^2 + y^2 - 1)/( 2 x y)] dx dy, x=0..1, y=1..2 can you please try this one ? The wolfram alpha exceeds its computation time. This might be possible for a the mathematica ?

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the shape,

```
Plot3D[4 (x y)/\[Pi]^2 ArcCos[(y^2 + 3)/(4 y)] ArcCos[(x^2 + y^2 - 
      1)/(2 x y)], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 1, 2}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and from

```
Reduce[
     {
      4 (x y)/\[Pi]^2 ArcCos[(y^2 + 3)/(4 y)] ArcCos[(x^2 + y^2 - 1)/(2 x y)] == 0
      , 0 <= x <= 1
      , 1 <= y <= 2
      }, {x, y}
     ]
```

> 0 < x <= 1 && (y == 1 || y == 1 + x)

the expression should be integrable in the range `{x, 0, 1}, {y, 1, 1 + x}`

```
NIntegrate[
 4 (x y)/\[Pi]^2 ArcCos[(y^2 + 3)/(4 y)] ArcCos[(x^2 + y^2 - 
      1)/(2 x y)], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 1, 1 + x}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> 0.053240519638085381131

Comment: I think you're missing a `y` in the inner integral.

Comment: @Netsie, you are correct, I have corrected that now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. I have actually observed that the actual integral equation has always the 1+x upper range for y instead of the  value which I had earlier shared. I want to ask if the upper limit of the y integral is x+1, then this integral is integrable over the entire range ?

Comment: @Waqas, The expression is real and well behaved in `{x, 0, 1}, {y, 1, 1 + x}` , and complex for `y>1+x`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it surely does and I am pretty relieved.As I am not that efficient in mathematical language, can you elaborate a bit more what does well behaved mean ?

Comment: @Waqas, You should read what to do after [your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). With "well behaved" I mean without discontinuities in the function or its first derivatives.

Comment: I tried to vote up your answer but it does not allow me as I do not have the required reputation points.

Comment: Yes, [privileges](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) come with reputation, the way to get reputation is making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) , and sharing what you know by answering.

Comment: Read about reputation: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation